# How and where I can translate the sentence in a back-office?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How to generate translation for this line:

```
$this->l('Send an email to the supplier when his/her order status has changed.')
```

This string I need to convert into the other language. In translations folder I see a lines like this:

```
$_LANGADM['AdminStatusesa8f92721e361eceb4489636d29f56c21'] = '(text on other language)';
```

So how I can do this?

```
$_LANGADM['AdminStatuses********************************']
```

Following this [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Translations+in+PrestaShop+1.5),

> The identification key is built by combining the name of the controller from which the original string comes and the MD5 hash of the string itself.

But where I can add a translation?

[**upd**] Well, I did this manually, right in the translations file:

```
$_LANGADM['AdminStatuses'.md5('Send an email to the supplier when his/her order status has changed.')] = '{this message on other language}';
```

Strange that I can't do this somewhere in back-office or translations management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Localization  > Translations" area you can choose your language from a list.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I dont need to choose a language at all.

Comment: What I meant was that when you reach that page you will **have** to choose the language which you want to translate from a list.

Comment: I don't have any list there or I can't see it, can you please show it on image?

Comment: yes, was helpful, thanx, also there was a limitation of `max_input_vars` on the server.